# Action: "android.settings.SECURITY_SETTINGS" throws ActivityNotFoundException on Samsung Android 12

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, samsung-mobile, intentfilter

I have an intent to open BiometricsAndSecuritySettingsActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

On Samsung A52 with Android 12 I got `ActivityNotFoundException`

I've tryed to look at intent-filters via PackageManager:

```
val packageManager = context.packageManager
packageManager.getPackageInfo("com.android.settings", PackageManager.GET_INTENT_FILTERS)
```

But I didn's see anything about intent-filters.
May be it caused by a bug, which represented here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36908355

I've gone forward and tryed to look up about intent-filters via adb.
I've used `adb shell dumpsys package com.android.settings`. I've exported result to the file and found this lines:

```
android.settings.SECURITY_SETTINGS:
d32d8d9 com.android.settings/.Settings$BiometricsAndSecuritySettingsActivity filter d8ea29e
          Action: "android.settings.SECURITY_SETTINGS"
          Category: "sec.voice.category.DEFAULT"
          Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
          mPriority=1, mOrder=0, mHasStaticPartialTypes=false, mHasDynamicPartialTypes=false
```

The same info I've got on Android 9

But, here is the difference between. On Android 9 I have this:

```
b99cc29 com.android.settings/.Settings$BiometricsAndSecuritySettingsActivity filter  android.settings.SECURITY_SETTINGS:
          Action: "com.android.settings.action.SETTINGS"
          mPriority=1400, mOrder=0, mHasPartialTypes=false
```

But dumpsys from Android 12 doesn't have any:

```
d32d8d9 com.android.settings/.Settings$BiometricsAndSecuritySettingsActivity filter f7b917f
          Action: "android.intent.action.MAIN"
          Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
```

So, do you have any ideas how to redirect a user to the BiometricsAndSecuritySettingsActivity directly? Not by using `android.settings.SETTINGS`?

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this problem?

Comment: Please, shame the Samsung, they have deleted intent filter for this.
For now we are using intent to the SETTINGS